# a lot of node_modules make my mac inodes exhausted

Tags: node.js

I ran out of inodes this morning. And I found out that quite a proportion of inodes were used by `node_modules/`. It's not the biggest trouble maker, but it still haunt me a lot.

I have a project that made up of hundreds of addons. For each addon I have a separate `package.json` and `node_modules` for it. Since the user can choose to install any combination of my addons, I think this is a good practice to manage the dependencies separately. But it leave me so many small files and most of which are identical. e.g. `bootstrap`, `lodash`, `gulp`.

```
/project
    /addon_a
        /node_modules
        package.json
    /addon_b
        /node_modules
        package.json
```

I can think of 2 possible solutions:

1. Install the most common libs globally, and manage the versions by not upgrading too often.
2. Share common libs between addons, but how to?

*FYI: I think it was actually docker and its friends used up the inodes. And I've recovered by removing and managing some docker images. But I definitely believe it that node_modules will someday be the cause of the same problem.*

Comment: You're not using HFS+ on your Mac?

Comment: Regarding solution 2: Either install the modules one or more folders "higher", so that more or all modules can access them or use symbolic links - they might work for you. Otherwise just get a better File System.

Comment: @Dodekeract I want to keep one package.json for each addon. Is your suggestion possible then?

Comment: @robertklep It's `File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+`, so I think yes.

Comment: @hbrls in that case, I'm intrigued, because HFS+ doesn't have inodes (per se) and the HFS-equivalent should be dynamically created as long as there is free space. So AFAIK you shouldn't be able to run out of them, unless you're also running out of space.

Comment: @robertklep Still 9G/120G free space then. I will post a pic if I ran into that again. (Yes, I will.)

Comment: @hbrls 8% free is a bit on the low(-ish) side for modern filesystems (it used to be that some percentage was reserved, not sure if that's still the case). Your problems may be resolved if you make some extra room (not necessarily inodes).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `npm dedupe`?

it searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree, where they can be more effectively shared by multiple dependent packages.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

Comment: I thought it was for inside one package, not across several packages. I will have a try then.